# Managing dependencies for data analysis project

Tags: r, dependencies, dependency-management, data-analysis

> **EDIT**: Pipeline tools can help, see the [awesome list](https://github.com/pditommaso/awesome-pipeline).

I'm looking for a way to organize the scripts for a project that involves the analysis and transformation of several fairly large data sets. The scripts and data dependencies will evolve over time, so the organization scheme should be flexible. In addition, I want to benefit from multicore architectures and be able to execute code in parallel as much as possible.

I'm planning to split the analysis into individual R scripts. Each R script would save its workspace to an `.RData` file with the same name; in addition, each R script can have an arbitrary number of input dependencies that correspond to other R scripts.

Which tools can help me with this? In general, what are good practices for handling such data driven projects?

Comment: Create a package ...

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2910/how-to-efficiently-manage-a-statistical-analysis-project

Comment: @Roland: Thought about that, but why invent the wheel before checking if anyone has invented it already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem for quite some time. Searched the internet and read several articles and blog-posts about it. In the end simply copying other peoples ideas didn't work for me very well so I borrowed and integrated several advices found in various places. One general advice I can give is to start small and evolve from there adding things as your projects get more and more complicated. But always strive to make the whole workspace as modular as possible so that you can have a luxury of modifying one small corner of the structure without affecting the rest of the system.

Based on your description I would do the following:

- Separate data and analysis. This would have several advantages as you can have a folder like datasets and simply symlink it to all the relevant projects.
- Saving every output from each script is debatable. I tend not to do it for several reasons: 1) it will use much more space 2) sometimes you will like to include other tools (not only R) into your workflow and saving everything in ".RData" format will become an obstacle. Save to a more convenient format and only save the usable/needed parts.
- Separate reusable part of your code from the "main()" part which only calls functions, loads inputs and saves outputs. So you can make something like "/src/" that would be version-controlled. Other scripts that loads "datasets" and "src" functions should go elsewhere.

Here is something similar to what I currently do:

- Two main folders: **Datasets** and **Projects**.

  - **Datasets** have one folder per dataset. Each folder for one dataset includes several subfolders like: *input, output, meta* (etc. according to the needs).

    - *input* holds all raw files you initially received. Nothing modified here.
    - *output* has all your outputs from running and preprocesing data. In general I have one separate folder in output directory for every output I produce. Like output/foo1/ output/foo2/ .. And within those I have the scripts that produced them, RData files, etc.
    - *meta* has all additional files that can describe the dataset (emails, slides, descriptions etc).
  - **Projects** has one folder per project. Each project in turn has these subfolders: link to datasets, *output*, *meta*, *press* that contain: datasets, analysis outputs, meta information and presentable results (like papers or slides) respectively.

    - *output* is the main folder inside each project. It contains one folder per analysis performed. Within that folder I place: Rmd (R-markdown) script. This in turn gets transformed into markdown and figures by knitr. And in turn to pdf and html by your program of choice (pandoc, multimarkdown etc).
- main functions (src) are shared for both Analysis and Datasets and version controlled. You can make a package out of it, but I tend not to do that.
- I also have a static content management system and a simple script that searches for html and produces a static website with navigation based on my Project directory tree for quick reporting of results.

For automation and checking dependencies GNU Makefiles is probably still the best bet (I currently don't use them but plan to). In the end you still probably will not want to have one global makefile for the whole structure. Having one per analysis (in a respective analysis folder) is often a better idea.

---

Here are some people discussing same things for reference:

1. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2910/how-to-efficiently-manage-a-statistical-analysis-project . This is a very similar discussion in cross-validated section of SE.
2. http://www.bioinformaticszen.com/post/decomplected-workflows-makefiles/ . Some descriptions of how you can incorporate makefiles into data analysis.
3. http://www.ploscompbiol.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pcbi.1000424 . Paper about organization of projects.
4. http://arkitus.com/patterns-for-research-in-machine-learning/ . Blog post about organizing project structure.
5. https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4384317 . Hacker news discussion.